# Number of Even Permutations in $S_6$

Tags: group-theory

What is the number of even permutations in S6?
If a permutation have two or more cyclic decomposition , then they are either an even permutation or odd permutation.
I am having  promblem while listing the permutations.
I am studying group theorey all by myself.
Do tell me how to calculate the even and odd permutations in a symmetric group.
Thankyou

Comment: Are you familiar with the sign of a permutation giving a homomorphism?

Comment: No sir I am not

Comment: Ok, another way then: Consider the map $S_6\to S_6$ given by $\sigma\mapsto (12)\sigma$. Do you see that this is a bijective map? What does it do to even permutations?

Answer (score 1):

The sign function ${\rm sgn}:S_n\rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$ assigning to each permuation $\pi$ the sign ${\rm sgn}(\pi)$ is for $n\geq 2$ a surjective homomorphism. As it is a group homomorphism, each image is taken on equally often. Thus $A_n = \{\pi\mid{\rm sgn}(\pi)=1\}$ has cardinality $n!/2$.